# How to get objects from array nested in another object in array with ES6

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2017

I have data with the following structure:

```
var DATA = {
'device_groups': [{
  'id': '1',
  'name': 'group 1',
  'devices': [{
    'id': 11,
    'name': 'device 11',
    'active': 1
  }, {
    'id': 12,
    'name': 'device 12',
    'active': 0
  }, {
    'id': 13,
    'name': 'device 13',
    'active': 0
  }] 
}, {
  'id': '2',
  'name': 'group 2',
  'devices': [{
    'id': 21,
    'name': 'device 21',
    'active': 1
  }, {
    'id': 22,
    'name': 'device 22',
    'active': 0
  }, {
    'id': 23,
    'name': 'device 23',
    'active': 1
  }]
}, {
  'id': '3',
  'name': 'group 3',
  'devices': [{
    'id': 31,
    'name': 'device 31',
    'active': 1
  }, {
    'id': 32,
    'name': 'device 32',
    'active': 0
  }, {
    'id': 33,
    'name': 'device 33',
    'active': 1
  }]  
}]
};
```

From all these "device_groups" arrays and inner "devices" arrays I need to get a single array of objects where 'active' is true (1).

How to do it the ES6+ way?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Andreas Tried to use map and filter, but got lost somewhere in the middle. Tried to do it step by step but somehow got an array of arrays...

Comment: Then please add your approach and we will help you to fix it. SO is not a "I need ... Please give me a solution" service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) like this:

```js
var DATA={'device_groups':[{'id':'1','name':'group 1','devices':[{'id':11,'name':'device 11','active':1},{'id':12,'name':'device 12','active':0},{'id':13,'name':'device 13','active':0}]},{'id':'2','name':'group 2','devices':[{'id':21,'name':'device 21','active':1},{'id':22,'name':'device 22','active':0},{'id':23,'name':'device 23','active':1}]},{'id':'3','name':'group 3','devices':[{'id':31,'name':'device 31','active':1},{'id':32,'name':'device 32','active':0},{'id':33,'name':'device 33','active':1}]}]}

const filtered = DATA.device_groups.map(a => a.devices.filter(a => a.active === 1)),
  output = [].concat(...filtered);

console.log(output)
```

Or using a simple [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
var DATA={'device_groups':[{'id':'1','name':'group 1','devices':[{'id':11,'name':'device 11','active':1},{'id':12,'name':'device 12','active':0},{'id':13,'name':'device 13','active':0}]},{'id':'2','name':'group 2','devices':[{'id':21,'name':'device 21','active':1},{'id':22,'name':'device 22','active':0},{'id':23,'name':'device 23','active':1}]},{'id':'3','name':'group 3','devices':[{'id':31,'name':'device 31','active':1},{'id':32,'name':'device 32','active':0},{'id':33,'name':'device 33','active':1}]}]}

const devices = DATA.device_groups
                  .reduce((a,d) => a.concat(d.devices.filter(f => f.active)),[]);

console.log(devices)
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like what I needed and waaay more efficient than what I tried to do...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

By filter we take out only the elements from `devices` which are having status `active` and than we concat them in `final output`

```js
var DATA={'device_groups':[{'id':'1','name':'group 1','devices':[{'id':11,'name':'device 11','active':1},{'id':12,'name':'device 12','active':0},{'id':13,'name':'device 13','active':0}]},{'id':'2','name':'group 2','devices':[{'id':21,'name':'device 21','active':1},{'id':22,'name':'device 22','active':0},{'id':23,'name':'device 23','active':1}]},{'id':'3','name':'group 3','devices':[{'id':31,'name':'device 31','active':1},{'id':32,'name':'device 32','active':0},{'id':33,'name':'device 33','active':1}]}]}

let output = DATA.device_groups.reduce((op,cur)=>{
  let temp = cur.devices.filter(ele=> ele.active)
  op = op.concat(temp)
  return op;
},[])

console.log(output)
```

Comment: You should explain what you've done otherwise this is just a code-dump.

Comment: @Andy Sure. was in the process of adding explanation to answer.

Answer (score 0):

basically you can use `reduce` and `filter` to achieve what you want

```js
var DATA = {
  'device_groups': [{
    'id': '1',
    'name': 'group 1',
    'devices': [{
      'id': 11,
      'name': 'device 11',
      'active': 1
    }, {
      'id': 12,
      'name': 'device 12',
      'active': 0
    }, {
      'id': 13,
      'name': 'device 13',
      'active': 0
    }]
  }, {
    'id': '2',
    'name': 'group 2',
    'devices': [{
      'id': 21,
      'name': 'device 21',
      'active': 1
    }, {
      'id': 22,
      'name': 'device 22',
      'active': 0
    }, {
      'id': 23,
      'name': 'device 23',
      'active': 1
    }]
  }, {
    'id': '3',
    'name': 'group 3',
    'devices': [{
      'id': 31,
      'name': 'device 31',
      'active': 1
    }, {
      'id': 32,
      'name': 'device 32',
      'active': 0
    }, {
      'id': 33,
      'name': 'device 33',
      'active': 1
    }]
  }]
};
const deviceGroups = DATA.device_groups;

const solution = deviceGroups.reduce((result, devicegroup) => {
  const filteredDevices = devicegroup.devices.filter(device => device.active === 1)
  return [...result, ...filteredDevices]
}, [])

console.log(solution)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `reduce` merge the inner array of `devices` from every `device_groups` into one array of `devices`. Then filter the merged array with `active === 1` to get one single array of devices which are active.

```js
var DATA = {"device_groups":[{"id":"1","name":"group 1","devices":[{"id":11,"name":"device 11","active":1},{"id":12,"name":"device 12","active":0},{"id":13,"name":"device 13","active":0}]},{"id":"2","name":"group 2","devices":[{"id":21,"name":"device 21","active":1},{"id":22,"name":"device 22","active":0},{"id":23,"name":"device 23","active":1}]},{"id":"3","name":"group 3","devices":[{"id":31,"name":"device 31","active":1},{"id":32,"name":"device 32","active":0},{"id":33,"name":"device 33","active":1}]}]};

var devices = DATA.device_groups
                  .reduce((acc, ele) => {
                     acc = acc.concat([...ele['devices']]); //merging each device array with the next with the concat().
                     return acc;
                   },[])
                  .filter((data) => data['active'] === 1);
console.log(devices);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use just `forEach` and spread `...` operator and push filtered results where `active` property is true, in final array

```js
var DATA = {'device_groups': [{'id': '1','name': 'group 1','devices': [{'id': 11,'name': 'device 11','active': 1}, {'id': 12,'name': 'device 12','active': 0}, {'id': 13,'name': 'device 13','active': 0}] }, {'id': '2','name': 'group 2','devices': [{'id': 21,'name': 'device 21','active': 1}, {'id': 22,'name': 'device 22','active': 0}, {'id': 23,'name': 'device 23','active': 1
  }]}, {'id': '3','name': 'group 3','devices': [{'id': 31,'name': 'device 31','active': 1}, {'id': 32,'name': 'device 32','active': 0}, {'id': 33,'name': 'device 33','active': 1}]}]};

const result =[];
DATA.device_groups.forEach(devGroup => result.push(...devGroup.devices.filter(d => d.active)));
console.log(result);
```